# Nullifying elements that doesnt match condition in list using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an POJO like so,

```
class Val {
    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

Now I've got a `List<Val> values`. I'm trying to obtain all the elements from `values` that has name `"ABC"` such that the elements in the list that doesn't have the matching name should be null.

For example:

```
List<Val> values = [Val(name=ABC,value=val1), Val(name=DEF,value=val2), Val(name=ABC,value=val3), Val(name=ABC,value=val4)]

values.stream().filter(x -> x.getName().equals("ABC")).collect(); //this will filter out the matching elements. This I know.

//Expected Output. Not sure how to do this.
List<Val> valuesOut = [Val(name=ABC,value=val1), null, Val(name=ABC,value=val3), Val(name=ABC,value=val4)]
```

Size of both the input and output lists remain the same. Only the elements with names not as ABC is turned to `null`.

Any suggestions on how to do this using streams?

Comment: Are you looking for `List<Val> valuesOut = values.stream().map(x -> x.getName().equals("ABC") ? x : null).collect(Collectors.toList());`?

Comment: Actually yes. Didn't know that we could map the element onto itself. Much appreciate the help. If you would put it up as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: When your list is mutable, you can also do this in-place. `values.replaceAll(x -> x.getName().equals("ABC")? x: null);`